# Authorizing javaee websocket request from HttpSession

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, websocket, java-websocket

I am using `javaee-websockets` for a small chat application integrated with a large `servlet 3.0` application. I want only authorized user to access the chat app and authorization is done via a servlet and authorization keys are added in `HttpSession`.

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket010.htm#BABJAIGH) I came to about using `HttpSession` in configuration class for `websocket serverendpoint` but I am unable to get how to block handshake of unauthorized user from here?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to block the handshake process.

If you define the authorization/authentication for WebSocket endpoints (represented by URI paths) in web.xml, Servlet implementation won't even start the handshake process for unauthorized users/request.

Comment: I am using session variables for authentication, how can I define this authorization in web.xml other than defining filters?

Comment: You most likely need to use filters, since you have something custom declared. You might consider using stadard Java EE stuff - Basic/Digest/Cert/Form auth scheme and container defined roles/credential store..